# PFFile parse into SWIFT

Tags: objective-c, parsing, swift, ios8, xcode6

Am building an app in xCode 6-Beta3. When I run the app it crashes.

However if I //Comment// out this code below the app launches. With the code commented out images will load to the Parse library on new user signup, since the table was created. One can see and download them from Parse too. So they are posting

But the app still won't preview the images. Any expert help is appreciated. Thanks

This is the error when run: Thread 1 EXC_BAD INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I138_IVNPO, subcode=0x0

// Profile Image code which crashes app//

```
            cell.profileImageView.alpha = 0

            let profileImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as PFFile

            profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)->Void in

                if !error{
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling cell.profileImageView.image = image inside this function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath         indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as YourCustomCellClass



// Configure the cell...

return cell
}
```

Also make sure you set your cell's reuse identifier to "cell" on your storyboard

Comment: Please post the full view controller code and I will edit it for you to make it clearer...